# R: possible to make a radar chart, but 3d surface version with ggplot or plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Couldn't find any guidance on this in the various R chart galleries around the web.

I have data like this:

| YearMonth | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | bike | 100 |
| 202101 | car | 40 |
| 202101 | skateboard | 60 |
| 202102 | bike | 70 |
| 202102 | car | 30 |
| 202102 | skateboard | 50 |
| 202103 | bike | 50 |
| 202103 | car | 20 |
| 202103 | skateboard | 30 |

What I would like to see is a surface connecting 3 radar plots (one for each month). For this example it would be somewhat conical, since the sales are decreasing over time on each product.

Is something like this achievable in R with ggplot or plotly?

Comment: No for ggplot2.  ggplot does not do 3D graphs.  There are some other packages like "rgl" that are better suited for 3D.  I would recommend against that since I believe a 3D radar chart would be too complex for the reader to quickly understand.

Comment: It's certainly possible, since ultimately you could work out the vertices of such an object and plot the resulting mesh in one of several ways. However, I'm not aware of any package that would allow this kind of thing to be done easily. Also, I agree with @Dave2e - surely this would be a very uninformative graphic even though it might look cool. Do you have a link to such a plot to give us an idea of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I tend to agree with [Dave2e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5792244/dave2e) , but I learned some things trying to code this.
Even a basic radar chart in ggplot2 is not obvious.
First I had to repeat the bike data so `geom_path` knows to close the polygons.
Then I had to modify `coord_polar()` slightly to force straight lines.
Then I used the `rayshader` package to make it 3-D.
One gotcha here is you needing to use the guides() function (not scale_color_continuous(guide = "none") to turn off the guide.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rayshader)

df <- data.frame(
  YearMonth = c(202101L,202101L,202101L,
                202102L,202102L,202102L,202103L,202103L,202103L),
  Product = c("bike","car","skateboard",
              "bike","car","skateboard","bike","car","skateboard"),
  Sales = c(100L, 40L, 60L, 70L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 20L, 30L)
)
df <- rbind(df, subset(df, subset = Product == "bike"))
df$height <- match(df$YearMonth, sort(unique(df$YearMonth)))
df

# Define a new coordinate system from coord_polar
coord_radar <- function(theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1, clip = "on") {
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x")
    "y"
  else "x"
  ggproto(NULL, CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start,
          direction = sign(direction), clip = clip,
          # This is the change to make the lines straight
          is_linear = function() TRUE
          )
}

plot2d <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Product, y = Sales, color = height)) + 
  geom_path(aes(group = YearMonth)) + 
  scale_color_continuous() +
  guides(color = "none") + 
  coord_radar()

plot_gg(plot2d, raytrace = FALSE)
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort! FTR i tend to agree with all 3 of you - was just trying to come up with some cool way to show the evolution of the sales categories over time - a transcluscent "tube" expanding/contracting along its vertical axis seemed like it might be cool. i can certainly simply do a faceted chart, either radar or other instead. :)